# Recover IQ samples from signal

Tags: demodulation

I have a data acquisition device that provides me with an array of integers that represents a modulated signal (let's say QAM16).

I would like to recover the I and Q samples from the raw time-domain signal, so that I can demodulate the data. Is this possible? If so, how would I do it.

Comment: Ideally that's what the samples already are.  If not, you need to explain what they represent.  Hopefully, if you only have one vector of samples, the signal is still at a non-zero IF, and you can use a pair of mixers fed by the sine and cosine of the center frequency to downconvert it.  But first you have to explain *what you are starting with*.

Comment: The returned results are just normalized amplitude values.

Comment: Can you explain a little more about what filters would be used?

Comment: Yeah, it is not clear what your samples really are. So, you have samples of the modulated carrier? And you sampled at more than 2x the carrier frequency?

Answer (score 1):

> I have a data acquisition device that provides me with an array of integers **that represents** a modulated signal (let's say QAM16).

The key here is **how** they represent the modulated signal. Once you know that, you can reverse the representation.

Unfortunately, there are more ways to represent the data being transmitted than there are acronyms in the QAM/QPSK/GMSK etc etc family.

Find out what your integers represent. What rate they're sampled, what the underlying data rate is, whether it's an IF, or IQ baseband, whether synchronous to the data symbols or whether you'll need to recover the timing clock.